# Volume of $ x^2-3 \le y \le 1 $ around $ y = 2 $

Tags: calculus, integration

I need to calculate the volume of  $$ x^2-3 \le y \le 1 $$  around $$ y = 2 $$

My initial thought was to try

$$ {2 \cdot \pi} \int_0^2 (x^2-3)^2 \,dx $$

But then it hit me that because the function is negative within these bounds, I'm probably going to get the wrong answer, and I did. But at the same time, the I'm squaring $ r = f(x) $, so it shouldn't matter.. Ughh. Honestly, I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the volume is $$2\pi\int_0^2 [(5-x^2)^2 - 1]dx.$$

the reason is you get a washer for the volume element whose outer radius is $2-y = 2-(x^2 - 3) = 5 -x^2$ and the inner radius is $1.$